# Can't select value in datagridview combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview (InvoiceItems) with a field with VAT-rates (fldVatRateID). In the DGV I wont to dislplay a combo box so I can select pre-definied values (1 = 0%, 2 = 6%, 3 = 12% and 4 = 21%). I set the properties for that DGV-field as follows:
[Combobox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj0cM.png)
But when I run the program I can't sellect a value in the combobox:
[Select Value in combobox fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEVjo.png)
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked the combo boxes DataSource `TblVatRatesBindingSource`? If there is nothing being displayed then this usually indicates the combo box items are not getting filled properly. Without seeing the code this is pure speculation.

Comment: Thanks JohnG. At this moment there is no code, I have all doing in the form designer view. There is a little arrow in the upper-right corner of the tblVatRatesBindingSouce at the bottom of the designwindow. If I click that littlte arrow I can choose for "Preview data ..." then there opens a new window where I can preview the data and all the data thats in the VAT-table is shown, so the bindingsource is OK I think If I could insert (or send) some images I would show you the data.

Comment: Also this code in Form_load_event :
`Me.tblVatRatesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.dsInvoices.tblVatRates)`

Comment: ...Without looking at the code, speculation is the best you may get. If you are positive the table has data for the combo box, then you are most likely are not hooking it up properly.

Comment: Sorry sir, If there is no  code I can't show you some code. I'm sure the data is loaded into the InvoiceRatesTableAdapter and also the source is linked (hooked up) to the object as you can see in the object properties (see image Combobox settings)

Comment: If there is no code, then how is the program running? If you are doing all this in the designer, then look at its auto generated code. I mean there has to be some code. If everything is hooked up properly then you should be able to select the values in the combo box. If you can’t select different values in the combo box, then obviously something is incorrect. Again, without some code or step-by-step instructions of what you are doing in the designer, I am curious how you would expect others to offer any more than speculation since it is unknown what exactly you are doing.

Comment: You're right sir, there is a lot(!!) of hiden code, but I'm not a rocket cientist in visual basic. If I could send you the project I should do, but I can't. So I can only relay on people who wonna exam what to problem could couse. My step-by-step?
1) Drag a new datagridview to the form
2) Set properties for that grid and bind to datasource (wich works fine)
3) In datagridproperties window - Colums (Collection) I bind the VAT-ID field to the datasource as show in the figure screenshot in the question, and I load data in the formload event into the adapter, tha's what I do

Comment: If someone uses TeamViewer I invite them to see the problem live.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with VB and I have never got a Database correctly hooked up to a database using the designer. I would normally hook the `DataGridView` up in code using a `DataTable`, so I may have overstepped my bounds here. Try getting your data into a `DataTable` and then set it as the `DataSource` to the `DataGridView` manually. I am aware that you state you are hooking this up correctly, however since the data is not appearing, it must be one of two things. 1: the data is not there (which you state is present) or 2: it is not hooked up properly to the `DataGridView`.